# Why I can't see native android logs from react-native package java files?

Tags: android, react-native

could you help me understand why I don't see logs in java files of react-native package in Android Studio?

I tried other packages and everything works fine (see added logs in Android Studio). In case with react-native package that doesn't work.

For example, I tried to add logs to any java file in `node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textInput` folder and don't see them.

Maybe there is any default config that prevents showing the logs for android files? like Proguard or something similar

If you know the reason, please hint me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you open the logcat in Android Studio, logs are shown. 
or you'd like more specific information, go to this website: https://developer.android.com/tools/logcat

Comment: @PratikPrakashBindage, logcat shows logs, but not the ones from react-native package